# Python regex remove dots from dot separated letters

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

I would like to remove the dots within a word, such that `a.b.c.d` becomes `abcd`, But under some conditions:

- There should be *at least 2 dots within* the word, For example, `a.b` remains `a.b`, But `a.b.c` is a match.
- This should match on 1 or 2 letters only. For example, `a.bb.c` is a match (because `a`, `bb` and `c` are 1 or 2 letters each), but `aaa.b.cc` is not a match (because `aaa` consists of 3 letters)

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
import re
texts = [
    'a.b.c', # Should be: 'abc'
    'ab.c.dd.ee', # Should be: 'abcddee'
    'a.b' # Should remain: 'a.b'
]
for text in texts:
    text = re.sub(r'((\.)(?P<word>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})){2,}', r'\g<word>', text)
    print(text)
```

This selects "any dot followed by 1 or 2 letters", which repeats 2 or more times. Selection works fine, but replacement with  group, causes only on last match and repetition is ignored.

So, it prints:

```
ac
abee
a.b
```

Which is not what I want. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting the match with a `.` dot not make sure that there is a char a-zA-Z before it.

If you use the named group `word` in the replacement, that will contain the value of the last iteration as it is by itself in a repeated group.

---

You can match 2 or more dots with 1 or 2 times a char a-zA-Z and replace the dots with an empty string when there is a match instead.

To prevent `aaa.b.cc` from matching, you could make use of word boundaries `\b`

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{1,2}){2,}\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent the word being part of a larger word
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 times a char a-zA-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` Match a dot and 1 or 2 times a char a-zA-Z
- `){2,}` Close non capture group and repeat 2 or more times to match at least 2 dots
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD9BMr/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1PslxC)

```
import re

pattern = r"\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{1,2}){2,}\b"
texts = [
    'a.b.c',
    'ab.c.dd.ee',
    'a.b',
    'aaa.b.cc'
]

for s in texts:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().replace(".", ""), s))
```

Output

```
abc
abcddee
a.b
aaa.b.cc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?=(?:.*?\.){2,}.*$)[a-z]{1,2}(?:\.[a-z]{1,2})+$
```

You can use this to match the string.If its a match, you can just remove `.` using any naive method.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/BrNBtk/1